# Doctrine - Set $id as UUID instead of Integer when creating new entity

Tags: doctrine, symfony5

I am working on a new project in Symfony 5.3. I am using this command `bin/console make:entity` for creating entities.

This wizard automatically creates an entity with `$id` as primary key of type integer. I am prefering UUID instead of integer.

How I should change settings to get Entity like this?

Thank you

```php
namespace App\Entity;
    
use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\IdGenerator\UuidGenerator;
    
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EventRepository::class)
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UuidGenerator::class)
     */
    private $id;
    
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to set the generated identifier strategy on make entity.
You can see all available option using `php bin/console make:entity -h`

Also there are no configuration in doctrine.yaml file to define this.

It could be a good feature to add for current and next version

To request a new feature, you can create a new issue feature request type:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/new/choose
You will need a github account

Comment: Thank you for reply. Does the Symfony project has any whishlist?

Comment: i edited my answer with your need

Comment: Thank you @florent-cardot!